# How to organize and access URLS and TEMPLATES in django

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-urls

i have just begun learning Django, and i stick with the principle that the fastest and best way to learn is through practice. I'm on the process of building my first web app, and i would really appreciate your help on the following :

I'm working on getting the front end to show up. But i'm having a hard time understanding the way the URLS work.

I have the following directory :

```
/myApp
    /myApp
        /public
        /templates
            /account
                login.html
            base.html
        settings.py
        urls.py
        ...
    /account
        urls.py
        views.py
```

I have this on my myApp(the main app) 'urls.py' file

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ...
    url(r'^$', include(account.urls), name='account'),
)
```

And inside my account urls.py file, i already have the ff :

```
...
urlpatterns = patterns(
    'account.views',
    url(r'^$', 'login_user', name='login'),
)
```

I already defined following on the account views.py file :

```
def login_user(request):
    return render(request, 'account/login.html')
```

So i guess the request should render my login.html file.

But i get the error that,

```
NameError at /
name 'account' is not defined
```

Therefore, i've figured that there must be something wrong with my settings.py file, right?

So here it is if it serves some purpose (just the important stuffs) :

```
...
BASE_DIR = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '.')
...
ROOT_URLCONF = 'myApp.urls'
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'myApp.wsgi.application'
TEMPLATE_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates'),
] 
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')
STATIC_URL = "/static/"
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'public'),
]
```

Right now, i really need to at least get the front end working. I hope the details i gave you gives you an idea of how i am organizing my file right now.

Additional note : I want to just create one template directory for the whole app. And as you can see on the structure, the template folder is inside the main app. How do i configure it inside the settings such that the apps use the main template folder?

Answer (score 1):

You should put the `account.urls` in quotes.  Also remove the `$` sign from the regex:

```
url(r'^', include('account.urls')),
```

And in the `account/urls.py` file you should correct the base module name from `oauth` to the `acount` (your view is `account.views.login_user`, not the `oauth.views.login_user`):

```
urlpatterns = patterns('account.views',
    ....
)
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast response sir. I've done what you said. But i still get the "NameError at /". Sir, when i say "include('account.urls')" does the app find the file? Because my account app is located on the same directory as the main app.

Comment: Your settings suggest that `account` is not a top-level module. You probably need to change it to `'babyancestry.account.urls'`. As for your view function, the preferred method is to import the view function (`from babyancestry.account.views import login_user`) and use it directly, without the prefix argument or the quotes. All other methods will soon be deprecated and removed in Django 2.0.

Comment: What is the name of the `account` app in the `INSTALLED_APPS`?  Is it `"account"` or `"babyancestry.account"`?

Comment: I've edited my question's settings section sir. The babyancestry is a typo sir. It should be myApp.

Comment: I'm really sorry sir, but the ROOT_URLCONF should be the one inside the myApp folder.

Comment: Oops. Looks like i haven't defined the account app insdie the INSTALLED_APPS sir. Thank you so much.